# Passing array length to function

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. My fortran-fu is poor.

Is there a way in Fortran to pass the array length? Using `common` (which, from what I gather is equivalent to `global`) is an option as well. What I want is in the main program to call a function with an array. For example (This is typed in, not copy pasted from anywhere)

```
program prog
integer num
double precision x(num),v
double precision test

....
v=test(x,num)
....


function test(x,num)
double precision test
integer num
double precision x(num)
test=0.0d0
....
return
end
```

This won't compile since `num` is not a constant. The important thing is to know what the array size I'm passing is.

Edit: I'm using the GNU Fortran 95 compiler.

Edit2: I tried High Performance Mark's solution without luck:

```
  program prog
  integer v
  parameter (v=10)
  double precision x(v),test,k
  k=test(x)
  write (*,*) size(x)
  stop
  end

  function test(x)
  double precision, dimension(:),intent(in) :: x
  double precision test
  write (*,*) size(x)
  test = 0.0d0
  return
  end
```

The output should be two lines where 10 is written. Instead I got this:

```
/scpc:niels: #$ f95 err.f
/scpc:niels: #$ ./a.out 
           0
          10
/scpc:niels: #$
```

Comment: Another style comments beside the common blocks. There is no reason to use 'stop' or 'return' before the 'end'. `double precision` should avoided and changed to `real(rp)`, where `rp` might be `rp=kind(1d.0)` for simplicity or you use `selected_real_kind`.Also, indent tour code!

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for you comments. I use the same indention that Emacs use. As four your other comments, I'm updating my adivsor code and my fortran-fu is low. I suspect that I'll do more damage then good if I'll try and do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortran arrays 'know' how long they are, you shouldn't need to pass the array and its length as different arguments.  (Unless, that is, you are interfacing with old Fortran codes.)  Today you'd write something like this

```
function test(arr)
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: arr
    ...
    integer :: arrsize
    ...
    arrsize = size(arr)
    ...
```

If you have to interface to old code in which array sizes are passed you can make calls like this

```
  call old_fortran_subr(array, size(array, 1), other_arguments)
```

Oh, and while I'm writing, have nothing to do with `common` in any code you write from scratch, it's a (rightly) deprecated feature from the 70's and earlier.  Instead use *module variables*.

Comment: +1 Just for the last sentence. Common blocks should be avoided like the plague in any even vaguely modern dialect of Fortran.

Comment: I tried this without luck. I have edited my question with what I did. Where can I read about module variables?

Comment: My compiler (Intel Fortran 13.0) compiles your new code and writes `10` out twice.  Either what you have posted isn't a faithful copy of your code or you have problems I cannot see.

Comment: You can read about module variables right here on SO, among other places.

Comment: @Yotam: you have an assumed-shape array (`dimension(:)`) dummy argument in your function, which requires an "explicit interface". The easiest way to provide this is to make your function an internal procedure of the program, or of a module that you use in the program.

Comment: On the subject of module variables, while they are less bad than common still avoid them wherever possible. Global variables make code maintenance and development harder, it really is good practice to keep the scope of variables as small as possible, and it will save you time and energy in the long run.

Comment: Who knows from which version of Fortran the obligatory need of explicit declaration of array dimensions passed as parameters for subroutines are removed? i.e. we just have to declare "real, dimension(:,:) :: arr", rather than "real, dimension (3,5) :: arr". As @HighPerformanceMark said we need the former to interact with OLD Fortran codes, is it Fortran 77?

Answer (score 3):

OK, there's a lot going on here, especially as the Fortran style you are using is a little archaic. Let's do it by steps ...

Firstly make sure you always use implicit none

Secondly if you know the size of the array a priori you can use a symbolic constant to denote its size. You do this via a parameter:

```
Program prog

  Implicit None ! ALWAYS USE THIS

  Integer, Parameter :: num = 36

  Double Precision x( num )
  Double Precision test
  Double Precision v

  Call Random_number( x )

  v = test( x, num )

  Write( *, * ) v

End Program prog

Function test( x, num )

  Implicit None ! ALWAYS USE THIS

  Double Precision test

  Integer num
  Double Precision x( num )

  Integer i

  test = 0.0d0
  Do i = 1, num
     test = test + x( i ) * x( i )
  End Do

End Function test
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ gfortran -O -std=f95 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic func.f90
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ ./a.out
   12.129812171430215
```

Note how num is set to be 36, but the parameter bit means I can not change its value - it is a constant and so can be used to set the size of arrays.

And that is how things stood until 1990. Then a number of things came into the language which change the answer. Most directly connected to your question are allocatable arrays, which allow you to specify the size of the array at run time, and assumed shape arrays, which make passing arrays to subprograms simpler. However a whole slew of other things came in and I suggest you have a look in a book to learn about them - the new language is much more expressive and safer than the old. As an example I would write the above nowadays as something like

```
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ cat func.f90

Module numbers_module

  Integer, Parameter :: wp = Selected_real_kind( 12, 70 )

End Module numbers_module

    Module funcs_module

      Use numbers_module

      Implicit None

      Public :: test

      Private

    Contains

      Function test( x ) Result( sum_sq )

        Implicit None ! ALWAYS USE THIS

        Real( wp ) :: sum_sq

        Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Intent( In ) :: x

        sum_sq = Sum( x * x )

      End Function test

    End Module funcs_module

    Program prog

      Use numbers_module
      Use funcs_module

      Implicit None ! ALWAYS USE THIS

      Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: x 

      Real( wp ) :: v

      Integer :: num

      Write( *, * ) 'How many elements ?'
      Read ( *, * ) num
      Allocate( x( 1:num ) )

      Call Random_number( x )

      v = test( x )

      Write( *, * ) v

    End Program prog

    [luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ gfortran -O -std=f95 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic func.f90
    [luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ ./a.out
     How many elements ?
    39
       14.151818513394156
```

If you decide to go this way make sure you understand why to use this method an interface to test needs to be in scope at the calling point - and to do this read a book.

Oh. Common. Just Say No.

Answer (score -1):

Implicit variable declaration was used in earlier versions of Fortran. By this method of variable could simply be used without declaring it explicitly. One statement such as IMPLICIT REAL(A-H, O-Z ) would declare all real variables beginning with letters A-H and O-Z. This is now considered to be too loose and explicit type declaration such as is required by the more powerful language C is to be preferred. My first language was FORTRAN IV but the second language I learned was QBasic which like C requires that all variables be declared explicitly before use.

Comment: This has really nothing to do with the question. It is not an answer. After getting some reputation points for your real answers or question you will be able to post comments. However, do not post comments as answers. Certainly do not just rant about power of various languages.